# Reduce array of objects to render additional rows in a table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui

I have some data returned by an api call

```
    licenseInformation: [
  {
    licenseId: "b6068748363d3400",
    authorizedSerialNumbers: [
      {
        serialNumber: "simulated device"
      },
      {
        serialNumber: "2342432"
      }
    ],
    noneBefore: "*.*.*-0",
    noneAfter: "*.*.*-0"
  },
  {
    licenseId: "a6394523t4599000",
    authorizedSerialNumbers: [
      {
        serialNumber: "simulated device"
      },
      {
        serialNumber: "23412414124141412"
      }
    ],
    noneBefore: "1.*.*-0",
    noneAfter: "2.*.*-0"
  }
]
```

Each `licenseId` can have several `serialNumbers`. I want render each additional `serialNumber` in a new row in the table. I can't quite get the reduce method to do what I want. I have attempted the below:

```
const licenseBySerial = loadedLicenses.reduce((acc, l) => {
const { licenseId, authorizedSerialNumbers } = l;
if (authorizedSerialNumbers.length > 1) {
  const licenseList = authorizedSerialNumbers.map(sn => ({
    licenseId,
    serialNumber: sn.serialNumber
  }));
  acc.concat(licenseList);
  return acc;
}
const license = {
  licenseId,
  serialNumber: authorizedSerialNumbers[0].serialNumber
};
console.log(license);
acc.push(licenseBySerial);
console.log(acc);
return acc;
}, []);
```

I have a [codesandbox with the code here](https://codesandbox.io/s/licenses-87cl3)

Here's a picture with my desired outcome, with the red lines denoting where the additional `serialNumber(s)` should be rendered.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The first snippet is not exactly what you wanted, but I think it's OK. I created a table for the **serialNumbers** inside a cell.

```js
const l = [{
    licenseId: "b6068748363d3400",
    authorizedSerialNumbers: [{
        serialNumber: "simulated device"
      },
      {
        serialNumber: "2342432"
      }
    ],
    noneBefore: "*.*.*-0",
    noneAfter: "*.*.*-0"
  },
  {
    licenseId: "a6394523t4599000",
    authorizedSerialNumbers: [{
        serialNumber: "simulated device"
      },
      {
        serialNumber: "23412414124141412"
      }
    ],
    noneBefore: "1.*.*-0",
    noneAfter: "2.*.*-0"
  }
]

const tableRender = (d) => {
  let html = ''
  html += '<table>'
  d.forEach(e => {
    html += '<tr>'
    html += `<td>${e.licenseId}</td>`
    html += `<td>`
    html += '<table>'
    e.authorizedSerialNumbers.forEach(el => {
      html += '<tr>'
      html += `<td>${el.serialNumber}</td>`
      html += '</tr>'
    })
    html += '</table>'
    html += `</td>`
    html += `<td>${e.noneBefore}</td>`
    html += `<td>${e.noneAfter}</td>`
    html += '</tr>'
  })
  html += '</table>'
  document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = html
}

tableRender(l)
```

```css
table,
tr,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

2. The second snippet is what you were asking for. The table has rows according to the **serialNumber**s, but only display data in the first row of a **licenseId** (except for the **serialNumber**).

```js
const l = [{
    licenseId: "b6068748363d3400",
    authorizedSerialNumbers: [{
        serialNumber: "simulated device"
      },
      {
        serialNumber: "2342432"
      }
    ],
    noneBefore: "*.*.*-0",
    noneAfter: "*.*.*-0"
  },
  {
    licenseId: "a6394523t4599000",
    authorizedSerialNumbers: [{
        serialNumber: "simulated device"
      },
      {
        serialNumber: "23412414124141412"
      }
    ],
    noneBefore: "1.*.*-0",
    noneAfter: "2.*.*-0"
  }
]

const tableRender = (d) => {
  let html = ''
  html += '<table>'
  d.forEach(e => {
    e.authorizedSerialNumbers.forEach((el, i) => {
      html += '<tr>'
      html += `<td>${i === 0 ? e.licenseId : ''}</td>`
      html += `<td>${el.serialNumber}</td>`
      html += `<td>${i === 0 ? e.noneBefore : ''}</td>`
      html += `<td>${i === 0 ? e.noneAfter : ''}</td>`
      html += '</tr>'
    })
  })
  html += '</table>'
  document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = html
}

tableRender(l)
```

```css
table,
tr,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your examples. Any chance you can update the codesandbox link I posted?

Comment: Here's the result: https://037gh.csb.app, here's the code: https://codesandbox.io/s/licenses-037gh